# ls -h command in mac osx Catalina 10.15.2 not working

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos

I'm a newbie and this is probably a very newbie question (be forewarned). When using terminal with zsh, entering `ls -h` does not output the expected result. Instead I receive an output as if I just entered `ls` without the `-h`. What could be the cause of this? Does `ls -h` not function the same in zsh mode?

Edit: My expected outcome of running `ls -h` would be a more readable/understandable version of `ls -l`, displaying file sizes as `1.3k` etc.

Comment: Have you ascertained that changing the shell really does affect `ls`, or are you comparing the result of running the command on a Mac with that of a Linux-based system? Have you looked at `man ls` to see if the `-h` flag is defined to do what you expect? What _do_ you expect (you forgot to include that)? Please [edit] your question... don't comment here

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `ls -lh`?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the output of `type ls` in an environment where `ls -h` does what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just running `ls -h`, the `-h` has no effect.  From `man ls`:

> ```
> -h      When used with the -l option, use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte,
>         Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte in order to reduce the
>         number of digits to three or less using base 2 for sizes.
> ...
>   -l    (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  List in long format. (See below.)
> ...
> The Long Format
>    If the -l option is given, the following information is displayed for each
>    file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number of bytes
>    in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modified, hour
>    file last modified, minute file last modified, and the pathname...
> ```

If you want the sizes, then you'll want `ls -lh`:

```
$ /bin/ls -lh .zshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff   4.6K May 18 18:54 .zshrc
```

Comment: So just to clarify why do I have to use ls -lh, instead of ls -h?.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @zaddy `ls` just lists the files in the directory with no additional information. `-h` stands for "human readable" and it's referring to file and directory sizes. So using `-h` without `-l` is pointless because you don't see sizes in the first place without `-l`.
`-l     use a long listing format`

Comment: @zaddy maybe in some other environment you had an alias `ls="ls -l"`?  Otherwise, I don't know of an implementation of `ls` where `-h` does anything if `-l` (or similar) isn't provided.

Comment: "When used with the -l option…"